# OSError: decoder jpeg not available on Windows

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am developing on a Django project and recently ran into a nasty problem. I installed the Pillow library on my Windows computer and it unexpectedly threw an OSError when trying to display an image in my Django template.

> OSError: decoder jpeg not available

How can I fix this?

---

This got downvoted the second I submitted it. So I feel forced to mention the following (I have my pride!):

- This is a Q&A (self-answered).
- I will go into detail in the answer.
- It's originally a blog post that took **me** several hours to write! It's my contribution, not someone elses I stole.
- Source: http://blog.danic.net/oserror-decoder-jpeg-not-available/

Comment: Is this your own blogpost? And did you just copy it verbatim?

Comment: Yes, it is my blog post. Most of it is verbatim.

Comment: +1 I don't know who -1'ed it without explanation. Probably because of the shameless plug. You are encouraged to answer your own question. The python ecosystem on windows needs posts like this that help even out the speedbumps.

Comment: I think the 2 paragraphs after the error should be part of the answer, not the question.. I tried to edit. But I think it wasn't accepted.

Comment: "The python ecosystem on windows needs posts like this that help even out the speedbumps." Chris, thank you for your support. This is why I shared my experience with the community. I saw your edits, but I'd even like to improve those parts to make it clear that this is a valuable contribution of mine and no question without "any research effort" behind it. I was saddened to see someone downvoted this without explanation.

Comment: [It is ok to link to your own work like this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20532/171231) This is no advertisement and the answer isn't [just the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171231)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, or this will stay open.

Comment: Someone has put a close vote on this question for "unclear what you're asking". If I were inclined to guess, I'd guess that the downvote (even if from someone else than the downvoter) was for this rather than any issue regarding authorship. (But authorship should still be clear. I'd suggest moving it in the answer though.) Although I disagree with the close vote, I can see where they are coming from. We get a *lot* of questions which consist of a small description + an error message, and this leads a whole bunch of answers based on hypotheticals.

Comment: One thing that would help the question look better would be to move the beginning of the answer into the question to say something like (paraphrasing here) "I've tried reinstalling and notice that the summary says ... jpeg is not installed. How can I fix this?" This way, the people who are searching for the error message would still get to this question, and people just stumbling upon it would most likely not have a problem with the contents of the question since it would have been narrowed down to something reasonably specific.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I made it look more like a question and will also simply link to my blog the next time. Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### A Short Explanation

This is because the Pillow package does not bring the required libraries. That’s something you need to take care of. Hence JPEG support (along with other file formats) is not available.

To verify this, have a look at the setup summary after installing Pillow. If you don't have that around, simplay reinstall the package and the summary will be shown.

```
$ sudo pip uninstall Pillow
$ sudo pip install Pillow
```

In the summary we see that I installed Pillow version 2.3.1 on Windows 8.1. Most importantly, we see that there is no support for JPEG and PNG (ZLIB) image files.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 2.3.1
platform     win32 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:24:06
             [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
(Tcl/Tk 8.6 libraries needed)
*** JPEG support not available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** LIBTIFF support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS2 support not available
*** WEBP support not available
*** WEBPMUX support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
```

### A definite Solution

On Linux, simply install package *libjpeg-dev* and reinstall the Pillow library.

But since we are working with Windows, we have to go a little deeper: We need to download the jpeg library sources to provide the header files and build the library file on our own. Also do some copy and paste.

You need to install [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/de-de/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_4). You need it anyway to build Pillow in the first place, or you end up with the error: [Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://blog.danic.net/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/).

Then download the [jpeg library package](http://www.ijg.org) from the Independent JPEG Group and extract it to a temporary location.

#### Copy the header files

In the jpeg package search for three files named

- jpeglib.h
- jmorecfg.h
- jconfig.h (edit: needs to be created, see comments)

and copy them into the *include* folder of your Python installation directory (probably *"C:\Python34\include\"*)

#### Build the library file

To be able to finish the next steps, run vcvarsall.bat. This will add all the necessary directories to your PATH variable. By default, you find this file in *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"*

Now open a command line and find the directory where you extracted the jpeg library source earlier on. Execute the following two commands:

```
> nmake /f makefile.vc setup-v10
> msbuild jpeg.sln
```

The second command builds the required file and places them in the newly created subdirectory *\Release\*.

#### Clean up and rebuild Pillow with JPEG support

Awesome, now we only need to copy the freshly built *Release\jpeg.lib* into our Python-libs directory (probably *"C:\Python34\libs\"*).
**Note:** "libs", not "Lib".

Once more, install the Pillow package and take care of the setup summery. JPEG support is now available.

```
--- JPEG support available
```

Comment: +1, I have no idea about the correctness of the solution (python on *nix is my cup of tea). But you took the time to markup your blogpost and share it with the world on a site with more chance for people to find it. Well done. You'll get more recognition once people that encounter this problem search for it.

Comment: there is no jconfig.h in any of the binary distributions I downloaded

Comment: Ah, this file must be created: https://www.falconview.org/svn/Sandbox/mapnik/libjpeg-8a/install.txt

Comment: @duhaime, thanks for the addition. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @duhaime that file is u/n p/w locked, rendering part of this answer now inaccessible, thus the entire answer useless. 

Any clues?

Comment: @twobob I'm sorry to say this is really jogging the memory and I don't have access to a Windows machine right now. I do recall that `pip install pillow` would install PIL and handle more dependencies, but I don't know if that will bring this dependency with it. Sorry!

Comment: @duhaime ah well. (undocumented) Python bindings for ImageMagick it is then. This is exactly why external linking is a terrible idea on SO.

Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Wildly guessing: https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg/blob/master/install.txt
Looks pretty good.

Specifically:
Configuring the software by hand
First, generate a jconfig.h file.  If you are moderately familiar with C,
the comments in jconfig.txt should be enough information to do this; just
copy jconfig.txt to jconfig.h and edit it appropriately.  <snip>  Once
you get it to run, it will write a suitable jconfig.h file, and will also
print out some advice about which makefile to use.

Feels right. Hope that helps

Comment: @twobob I think you're right about external linking. Would you want to post an answer with these notes in case they help others? Either way, I hope you're off and running!

Comment: It took me less time last night to do a complete solution in ImageMagick python bindings (https://gist.github.com/twobob/f5dd8a25195d730801df25bf048c3272) than it would have to do the build on windows. So I am gonna say no. however, at least the next person has the info to move forward now.